# Can't connect Hive with PowerBI using ODBC driver

Tags: hadoop, hive, powerbi, odbc

I'm trying to connect apache Hive in Hadoop ecosystem with Power BI in order to visualise the results.
I have installed Virtual Machine oracle VM in windows 11. I have installed also Hive 3.1.2 inside of my virtual machine.
When I try to connect Hive with Power BI using Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive, it fails.
the error it shows in ODBC is:
FAILED!

[Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1110) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct and confirm if SSL should be enabled for the connection.

If you could help me with a solution to my problem.

Comment: Is the cluster kerberized?

Comment: Are you using SSL?

Comment: Actually I'm still a newbie I didn't understand your questions. However, I didn't use any security layer whatsoever. I followed this link to isntall my Hadoop ecosystem. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu

Comment: That post says nothing about Hive, so is Hive actually running? What exact address did you give to powerbi?

Comment: Hive is running when I try to set the connection. The IP address is 192.168.43.60 I found it using the command ifconfig. I also followed this tutorial to set my bridge. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOcfI7bGEdI However I had the error in the ODBC Driver